# How can I count the number of occurrences of a specific value for different unique IDs in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have large dataset of over 10,000 entries. The dataset contains a unique ID, a year that an event occurred, and the size of that event. I want to count the number of events of above and below a specific threshold value for each unique ID. However, for events below the threshold, I only want to count the event if it occurred after a certain year.

As an example, let's say I have the below data:

```
Unique ID, Year, Size  
111, 1980, 1  
111, 1992, 2  
111, 2000, 4  
222, 1990, 5  
222, 1994, 3  
333, 1999, 2  
333, 2011, 5  
333, 2012, 2  
333, 2016, 1
```

I want to categorize how many events are either equal to or above size 3 for each unique ID. But I also only want to count events that are <=3 if they occurred after a specific year. For example, I only want to count events that occurred after 1980 for Unique ID 1, after 1992 for Unique ID 2, and after 2000 for unique ID 3.

Based on the above example data, I would be expecting the following result

Unique ID, <=3, >3

```
111, 1, 1    
222, 1, 1  
333, 2, 1
```

Comment: I suggest you just create different combinations of outputs for all the different filters/selections you want, because they're quite specific

Answer (score 1):

Because there is for each `Unique ID` different threshold year create `dictionary` for [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), so is possible filter, here by [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) for less method with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
d = {111:1980, 222:1992, 333:2000}
df = df[df['Unique ID'].map(d).lt(df['Year'])]
print (df)
   Unique ID  Year  Size
1        111  1992     2
2        111  2000     4
4        222  1994     3
6        333  2011     5
7        333  2012     2
8        333  2016     1
```

And then for count is used [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df = pd.crosstab(df['Unique ID'], np.where(df['Size'].le(3), '<=3','>3'))
print (df)
col_0      <=3  >3
Unique ID         
111          1   1
222          1   0
333          2   1
```

Comment: Very nice combination of map and crosstab, and np.where, wow!